# Set up file not present

Tags: oracle, installation, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

I have downloaded and extracted the oracle 19c version. But I can not see any set up file.
How do I get the set up file!?
[Where I downloaded 19.5 Enterprise Edition](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/oracle-database-software-downloads.html)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which operating system you use nor which file exactly you downloaded, but - [Installing the Oracle Database Software](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ntdbi/install-oracle-database.html#GUID-5BD4C737-9215-4800-A935-3446A358A2A9) document says (for MS Windows)

> 3. Navigate to the location for Oracle Database 19c, open a command prompt with administrator privileges, and **run the setup.exe command**.

I wouldn't say that Oracle "forgot" to include it into the ZIP.